# scala/spark -- How to create a string which using a specified arbitrary byte array?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase

when I visit HBase using spark, I need to specify the correct scan range in HBaseConfiguration, then I create a RDD using the HBaseConfiguration. It seems like that below:

```
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, inputTable)
conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_START, start_row_string)
conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_STOP, end_row_string)
val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    conf,
    classOf[TableInputFormat],
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result]
  )
```

after that I can manipulate hBaseRDD in any way.
But that start_row_string in the code must be a string causes a problem.
In the HBase, my row key was created by a byte array starting with a Int.That is to say:

```
 val row_key = byte array of Int ++ arbitrary byte array
```

After I created the row_key byte array and transfer the row key into a string for passing into the HBaseConfiguration mentioned above,I found that I was wrong:

```
val row_key_string = new String(row_key)
```

Because the *row_key_string.getBytes* is not equals to *row_key*.so the HBase did not get the correct start row key,and HBase returns me a wrong data.
example:**

```
val arr = Array(0,0,15,-77)  //which is the array byte of 4018
val str = new String(arr)
arr.getBytes                 //return Array(0, 0, 15, -17, -65, -67)
arr.getBytes("UTF-16BE")     //return Array(0,0,15,-77)
```

*arr.getBytes("UTF-16BE")*   returns the correct answer.since method *getBytes* is called by spark,I can not specifiy the charset of getBytes.

If I can not solve the problem. I must give up the NewAPIHadoopRDD. I could establish a connection in each executor, and use Scan which adopts a byte array to specify the start row key provided by HBase Client.But it's ugly.

Comment: changing the default charset of jvm may help.but I fear that spark or hadoop will depend on the default charset. So changing the default charset would cause some problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my question by using TableInputFormat.SCAN.It is a BASE64 string.
And it is wrong to transfer a arbitrary byte array to string,because it's behavior is not controlled.